# Asymptotic hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing

What is meant by the notion of "consistent hypothesis test"? I am unfortunately not able to find a source in the internet, answering this questions.

Comment: Consistency says that as you get more and more data you get closer and closer to the exact true nswer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_estimator

Comment: Yes, but I am not asking for "consistent estimator". I am asking for "consistent test".

Comment: @LocalVolatility Of course, the questions is not directly linked to quantitative finance. But nevertheless, it is highly linked!

Comment: @Xarrus The article AlexC links to has a link to the relevant page at the top ("*For a broader coverage related to this topic, see [Consistency (statistics)*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_(statistics)).). The definition is under ["Tests"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_(statistics)#Tests).  I'd also add that when I just searched *consistent hypothesis test* (the phrase you quoted in your question) in google, three of the first four hits I got contained the answer to your question -- which makes me wonder what you can have been doing to find an answer on the internet

Answer (score 3):

A test is called *consistent* if the [asymptotic power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power) is 1, that is, as $n \rightarrow \infty$ the test will reject the null $H_0$ with probability 1 given that an alternative $H_a$ is true.

Comment: Can you formalize your answer?

Comment: @Xarrus what do you mean *formalize*? The answer is a correct definition -- it's not clear what you're asking for.